# Fomento de clics accidentales: diseño (Admob-Android)

Tags: android, flutter, admob, google-adsense

Hola hace una semana implemente anuncios nativos en una app con anuncios normales y recibo este error. Adjunto una imagen de como tengo mi anuncio nativo para ver si me pueden ayudar viendo si el diseño del anuncio esta mal. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:id="@+id/card_view" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp" card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_banner_small_icon" android:background="@drawable/rounded_image_border" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" tools:background="#EDEDED" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_banner_small_attribution_large" android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:background="#F19938" android:gravity="center" android:text="Ad" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:visibility="invisible" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginStart="80dp" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_banner_small_headline" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="end" android:lines="1" android:maxLines="1" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="16sp" tools:text="Headline" />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="2">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_banner_small_attribution_small" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:text=" Ad " android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_banner_small_body" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="end" android:lines="1" android:maxLines="1" android:textColor="#828282" android:textSize="14sp" tools:text="body" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

Comment: ¿Cual error es el que recibes? ¿Cual es el código que realizas?

Comment: El error es el del titulo Fomento de clics accidentales: diseño en admob, el codigo del anuncio nativo lo acabo de agregar

Comment: Perdón acabo de ver que es Flutter, pero ya veo en base a tu layout cual es el problema!

Comment: Podría ayudarme explicando cual es problema? Gracias

Comment: envuelve tu publicidad con una etiqueta que indique que es publicidad pero tambien ten en cuenta que al estar cerca de los botones, es una mala practica y quizas por eso te indique lo de los clics

Answer (score 0):

El problema es debido a que como indican los guidelines, el usuario puede dar clic accidentalmente a los anuncios  y esto puede ocasionar que los anuncios en tu app sean deshabilitados.

Este es el mensaje que seguramente recibiste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Debes evitar que los usuarios den clic a anuncios de forma accidental, por ejemplo, anuncios que se encuentran cerca de áreas donde el usuario da clic a otros elementos y esto puede provocar que se registren clics de forma no orgánica.
- Debes evitar que tu anuncio aparezca poco después de que se haya cargado una nueva pantalla/página de contenido debido a la latencia, en este caso debe mostrar el anuncio, dentro del método `onAdLoaded()`

Comment: Al final mande a revisión la app y me dijeron que no hay un problemas con las políticas, creo entonces que no era problema de mi implementación. Benditos errores de admob hacen asustar.